# Where is "Get Info" in Xcode 4.2?

Tags: ios-appstore, xcode

I have problems publishing my Application in the App Store.

It seem that the UI has been updated, but the tutorial I use still uses the old version of Xcode, and I can't follow the instructions to publish my application.

Where can I find the `Get Info` window in Xcode 4.2?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you mean with 'Get Info'

Comment: @voidStern `Open the Xcode project and Duplicate the “Release” configuration in the Configurations pane of the project's Info panel. Rename this new configuration “Distribution”.`Where can I find 'project's Info panel'?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Select your project in the right sidebar, then select the project in the main area above your targets. You'll find the configurations under the tab 'info'.